# How to create a single struct statement to declare an array and initialize?

Tags: c

I have the following code so far, I am pretty sure I can make the explicit initialization with multiple statements but I want to learn how to do it with a single one.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define LUNCHES 5

int main(void)
{
    struct Food
    {
        char *n;  /* “n” attribute of food */
        int w, c; /* “w” and “c” attributes of food */
    }

    lunch[LUNCHES], 
    lunch[0] = {"apple pie", 4, 100}, 
    lunch[1] = {"salsa", 2, 80};
}
```

I am thinking the following would work but it is another statement.

```
 int main(void)
 {
     struct Food
     {
         char *n;  /* “n” attribute of food */
         int w, c; /* “w” and “c” attributes of food */
     }

     lunch[LUNCHES];
     lunch[0] = {"apple pie", 4, 100};
     lunch[1] = {"salsa", 2, 80};
```

Comment: Side note: You got your answer below, but for your future benefit, to assign a struct to a variable, this is the syntax: `lunch[0] = (struct Foot){"apple pie", 4, 100};` which was introduced in C99.

Comment: Right that is a good point too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there:

```
 = { [0] = {"apple pie", 4, 100}, [1] = {"salsa", 2, 80} }
```

would be an initialization for your array.

This is only if your compiler supports "designated" initializers that came with C99.

otherwise

```
 = { {"apple pie", 4, 100}, {"salsa", 2, 80} }
```

would also do.

Comment: Oh. I see, thanks... it makes sense. I was getting the conflicting error because I had multiple lunch[]

Comment: +1: I had no idea the former sample was even possible in C. Please tell me it was added long-after I learned the base-language (C89). I can think of about a zillion places I could have used this since then. The latter I was already aware of.

Comment: @WhozCraig, it was a GCC extension for a while, and was added to the C99 standard.

Comment: @dbaupp Thanks. Good to know I was only sleeping at the wheel and not outright ignorant on how to drive. Now i need to go see what else I missed in that standard update. Thanks again.

Comment: @WhozCraig, C99 is even replaced now by c11 :) And they add a lot of little things that make daily life easier, initializers that are arbitrary expressions (not only constants), `for`-loop variables, compound literals, ...

Comment: @JensGustedt I knew they added most all of that; I'm pretty sure I sacrificed a live-goat the day they added variable-declarations inline (as opposed to top-of-scope-only). but for whatever reason this slipped past my radar. duh.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
struct { ... } lunch[LUNCHES] = {{"apple pie", 4,100}, {"salsa",2,80}};
```

Answer (score 2):

you could define in this way

```
int main(void)
{
    struct Food
    {
        char *n;                                                            /* “n” attribute of food */
        int w, c;                                                  /* “w” and “c” attributes of food */
    }lunch[LUNCHES] = { {"apple pie", 4, 100}, {"salsa", 2, 80}};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this perhaps?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LUNCHES 5

struct Food {
   char *n;   /* “n” attribute of food */
   int w, c;  /* “w” and “c” attributes of food */
} lunch[LUNCHES] = {
    {"apple pie", 4, 100}, 
    {"salsa", 2, 80}
};

int 
main(void)
{
  printf ("lunches[0].n= %s\n", lunches[0].n);
  return 0;
}
```